# Is the same to add two vectors and then compute the norm of the resulting one to first compute the norm of both vectors and then adding those values?

Tags: vectors

This may be a dumb question but I pretty new in vector math and I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

What I'm asking is basically this:

$$\|\vec{v}\| + \|\vec{u}\| \stackrel{?}{=} \|\vec{v} + \vec{u}\| $$

Comment: Google "triangle inequality". Also see the definition of norm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space

Comment: That helped. Thank you @MichaelMorrow!

Comment: Counterexample: $\vec v=-\vec u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $||\vec{u}||+||\vec{v}||\ge||\vec{u}+\vec{v}||$, with the equality reached only in special cases ($u=0$, $v=0$ or $v=\lambda u$ for $\lambda>0$). This is called a "triangle inequality" for reasons obvious from the following picture:

[image]

(Every side in a triangle is shorter than the sum of the other two sides.)

Comment: This is actually a requirement in the definition of a norm space, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @ZiqiFan correct. The four required properties are $$||x||\geq 0$$ $$||x||=0\iff x=0$$ $$||\alpha x||=|\alpha|||x||$$ $$||x+y||\leq ||x||+||y||$$

Comment: Of course, but as OP has not said anything about their background, I assumed they were doing high school geometry or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the diagram of what it would look like. Below is the two dimensional case: from the cosine rule, we know that $$||u+v||^2=||u||^2+||v||^2-2||u||||v||\cos(x)$$
which directly implies that $$||u+v||\leq ||u||+||v||$$

which is the general [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

We have equality if either vector is zero or their directions are the same.
[image]